# Upload file on OneDrive in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi, onedrive

I'm creating an API in ASP.NET Core to upload files to OneDrive.

The workflow is that the user will make an API request with an attachment and I want to store that file into my OneDrive account, but the issue is that the example code I'm familiar with does open an authentication window for users. I don't want this because I want to store files into my OneDrive.

Looking for an expert opinion.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @saud khan, I think you need check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msgraph-dotnet-core-manage-files/) to learn how to upload file on OnDrive step by step.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the solution, in this doc users have to authenticate with their MS account and I do not want this because I have no concern with the user's account. Users are supposed to send a file through an API and I need to store that file into my personal OneDrive.